# How to make the threading be executed following a fequencey (say, every 3 sec) at a (relatively) accurate time considering function execution time?

Tags: python, multithreading, datetime, time

I want to run a function every 3 second, and I do have searched similar topics. However, I didn't find any solution that can indeed meet my requirement, and the key issue is that in these solutions, they do not consider the time of executing the function itself. Consider the following code.

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import threading

def counting():
    global  num
    time_now = dt.datetime.now()
    if num > 0:
        print(f'count: {num}, time now: {time_now}') 
        num -= 1
        t = threading.Timer(3.0, counting)
        t.start()

num = 5
counting()
```

This prints every 3.0 seconds. The main issue is that in a real case, in stead of `print(f'count: {num}, time now: {time_now}')` , I will call a function, say, `func1()`, which will take some time between 1 second and 2.5 seconds. Hence, the real interval time between two calls will be more than 3 seconds (about 4-5.5 seconds). How can I write it to be exactly (of course, very small error is allowed) every 3 seconds between two calls? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to use a [monotonic clock](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-time-monotonic-method/) to find out the current time, and subtract that from the time at which you next want your scheduled function to be called; then you know exactly how long you'll need to sleep for, regardless of how long your `func1()` took to execute.  Here's an example (I removed the threading since the logic is the same regardless of whether it's running in the main thread or some child thread):

```
import random
import time

def func1():
    seconds_to_sleep = random.randrange(1000, 2500) / 1000.0
    print("pretending to work for %f seconds" % seconds_to_sleep)
    time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)

def scheduled_function(scheduled_time, now):
    if (now > scheduled_time):
       print("scheduled_function was called %f seconds late" % (now-scheduled_time))
    else:
       print("scheduled_function was called %f seconds early" % (scheduled_time-now))

next_call_time = time.monotonic()  # schedule the first call to happen right away
while True:
    now = time.monotonic()
    time_until_call_time = next_call_time-now
    if (time_until_call_time > 0.0):
       time.sleep(time_until_call_time)  # wait until our next scheduled call-time
    scheduled_function(next_call_time, time.monotonic())
    func1()  # sleep for some unpredictable amount of time to simulate a workload
    next_call_time = next_call_time + 3.0  # each call should happen ~3 seconds after the previous call
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using the Ada programming language is very simple. Ada provides a "delay until" syntax allowing to delay until some future time.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting; use Ada.Calendar.Formatting;

procedure Main is
   task periodic;
   
   task body periodic is
      Now : Time;
      Future : Time;
      The_Delay : constant duration := 3.0;
   begin
      for I in 1..10 loop
         Now := Clock;
         Put_Line("Periodic message at time " & Image(Now));
         Future := Now + The_Delay;
         delay 1.0;
         delay until Future;
      end loop;
   end periodic;
   
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

A recent execution of this program results in the following output (Time is the UTC time zone):

```
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:26:46
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:26:49
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:26:52
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:26:55
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:26:58
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:27:01
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:27:04
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:27:07
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:27:10
Periodic message at time 2021-05-27 02:27:13
```

The variable The_Delay is a constant value indicating 3.0 seconds. The Now time is the time at the beginning of each iteration. The Future time is Now plus 3.0 seconds. The resulting time is not offset by the task execution as long as that execution does not exceed 3.0 seconds. In order to simulate a long task execution the task delays (sleeps) 1.0 seconds during each iteration. The "delay 1.0;" statement is an absolute delay while the "delay until Future;" statement is a relative delay.

Comment: Here, I am talking about Python. But thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got the answer myself. We need to use `schedule` module. See the examples in https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html

The following is my test code.

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import threading
import schedule

def job():
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())
    print(dt.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(2)

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(6).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(6).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(6).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)

t_end = dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(seconds = 20)

while dt.datetime.now() < t_end:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

You can see that I am letting it run for every 6 seconds (by applying three multithread parallel computing), and I do let it sleep for 2 seconds in the function `job()` to replace the real running time. And from the output result, you will see that it runs every 6 seconds instead of 8 seconds!

Comment: Relying on `dt.datetime.now()` will break when the user changes the system time.